# Summation of "products"

Tags: sequences-and-series, contest-math

Ok, I am pretty sure I won't get an answer because the question is somewhat hard, and I have done research to no prevail but how can I find the summation of ab if I know the summation of a and the summation of b?

Comment: with summation you mean $\sum_{n}a_n$? And you are asking if knowing  $\sum_{n}a_n$ and  $\sum_{n}b_n$ you can know  $\sum_{n}a_nb_n$

Comment: Can't really do it. But check out Summation by parts: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Summation_by_parts

Comment: @Shalop Thank you so much! Kind of complicated but it helps

Answer (score 1):

You can't.

$1\hspace{-0.05 in}+\hspace{-0.04 in}0 \: = \: 1 \: = \: 0\hspace{-0.04 in}+\hspace{-0.05 in}1 \;\;\;\;$ and $\;\;\;\; (1\hspace{-0.05 in}\cdot \hspace{-0.05 in}1)+(0\hspace{-0.04 in}\cdot \hspace{-0.05 in}0) \; = \; 1\hspace{-0.05 in}+\hspace{-0.04 in}0 \; = \; 1 \; \neq \; 0 \; = \; 0\hspace{-0.04 in}+\hspace{-0.04 in}0 \; = \; (1\hspace{-0.06 in}\cdot \hspace{-0.04 in}0)+(0\hspace{-0.04 in}\cdot \hspace{-0.05 in}1)$

Answer (score 0):

if you interpret "the sum of $ab$ " as

$$ \sum_n \sum_k a_n b_k $$

Then it is true that

$$ \left( \sum_n a_n \right )\left( \sum_k b_k \right ) = \sum_n \sum_k a_n b_k $$